# Shopify Dawn + Product Reviews App - Remove Star rating on product page, if no reviews

Tags: css, shopify

I want to remove the star rating from my products, if the product hasn't been reviewed yet.

[image: Current status]

I tried pasting `.spr-starrating[data-rating="0.0"] { visibility:hidden !; display: none; }`
and `.spr-badge[data-rating="0.0"] { visibility:hidden !; display: none; }` into the `main-product.css`.

A demo store similar to mine can be found [here](https://product-reviews-app.myshopify.com/products/pleated-heel-boot).

Comment: Can you please provide the code of your html? And is there a specific reason why you are asking a purely CSS solution, or are you open to other types of answers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible because the attributes are just not there. The only way to get the rating from attributes is by using the `aria-label` of a child component. This leaves you with a JS-based solution, as the CSS `:has()` selector still doesn't have good browser support.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.spr-starrating .spr-stars span').forEach((el) => {
  if (el.getAttribute('aria-label') === '0 out of 5 stars') el.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none' 
})
```

For a CSS-based solution, you could use

```
.spr-starrating:has(span[aria-label="0 out of 5 stars"]) {
  display: none;
}
```

But this won't work in every browser, especially Firefox. See [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-has) for more information. Using both approaches at the same time would be suitable then.

Keep in mind that the `aria-label` might also be different if your shop is in a language other than English and you'd need to change the snippets appropriately.